# Every year date should be filter based on september-yy to till date. So what can I put inside criterias?

Tags: vba

```
ws2.Range("A:I").AutoFilter 9, Criteria1:="?"  Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:= "?"
```

I want to filter a column based on September to till date. Every year it should take September to till date data.

Comment: You mean filter values from September of the current year until the present date? What format exactly are the cells in?

Comment: September of last year. Cell format is 14-Feb-16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that last year = 2015 *or* = this year - 1?

Try this

```
ws2.Range("A:I").AutoFilter Field:=1 _
    , Criteria1:=">=" & Format(DateSerial("2015", "09", "01"), "dd-mmm-yy") _
    , Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy")
```